# "Teching" in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm creating an FPS designed to be a high skill-ceiling movement based spectator e-sport (quite a mouthful). As part of the movement-based side of this game, I wish to introduce "teching" as in Smash. This movement would break one's fall damage and queue jump, but the part I'm really interested in is the timing.

How would I go about detecting if the player is just about to land?

Comment: Try using RayCasts downwards/along the player's velocity vector while the player is in the air, and calculate how imminent their landing is based on their present velocity. You're going to need to provide an attempt (with code) in your question before I (or probably anyone else) can further advise, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are three steps to [teching](http://supersmashbros.wikia.com/wiki/Teching) (breakfall) in Super Smash Bros:

1. When you are in midair and in a damaged state you are in a state
   called "tumbling", you can exit "tumble" by flicking the analog
   stick left and right quickly.
2. During a tumble state, if you collide
   with **any** surface and hit `L` or `R` within a few frames, you
   project your velocity onto a plane and add a velocity vector in the direction the analog stick is held (which can be neutral for a in-place tech).
3. During this time, the player enters a "teching" state, which cannot be canceled unless you tech off another wall or timeout.

The idea of multiple states: "Grounded", "Fall", "FastFall", "Tumble", "Tech" immediately necessitates some form of a [Finite State Machine](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html) (implicit or explicit). Finite State Machines are design patterns that can either simplify or complicate your code depending on how you use them. In this case, I would recommend creating a state machine via several scripts `class GroundedBehaviour : Behaviour {}`, `class FallBehaviour : Behaviour {}`, `class TechBehaviour : Behaviour {}`. You can then keep a reference to the active `Behavior` in your character controller. Notice the recurring `Behavior` part instead of `MonoBehaviour`. I recommend researching the difference between inheriting from `MonoBehaviour`, `Behaviour`, and `Component`, because it will help simplify your code when you understand the distinctions.

Once you have built a state machine there are four major considerations:

1. input handling
2. **dealing with collisions between arbitrary surfaces**
3. projection of the player's velocity onto the plane
4. adding some velocity to the player while they tech.

Input handling is probably the easiest part in the absence of multiplayer, but know that any competitive FPS will have several synchronized clients, and you have to deal with sending [player input](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/command.html) to other clients down the road.

The next issue is the question you asked (how to detect if the player is about to collide with the ground). This is the problem of colliding with any arbitrary surface. The solution that is easiest would be using this line in `FixedUpdate`:

```
if(Physics.CapsuleCast(lowerPoint, upperPoint, radius, velocity.normalized,
                       out hitInfo, velocity.magnitude * Time.deltaTime))
{
    //use hitInfo.normal to tech
}
```

With this code, you have the "when to tech" part out of the way, but you still need the "how to tech" part.

The next piece of the puzzle is projecting the player's velocity onto the ground, which is the easiest piece. All you need is one line: `velocity = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(velocity,hitInfo.normal);`

The last part is adding the tech onto the projected velocity, which means you will have something like this:

```
velocity += TechVelAdder(input /*Vector2 from analog stick*/,
                         hitInfo.normal /*Vector3 from the CapsuleCast earlier*/);`
```

I've dealt with code similar to teching for arbitrary walls and there's a lot of ways you can do it (and by a lot I mean infinite). That being said, here are two good ways:

```
Vector3 TechVelAdder1(Vector2 input, Vector3 normal) //this will always move the player in the direction of the input from a bird's eye view
{
    float techSpeed = 10f;
    float input3D = new Vector3(input.x, 0f, input.z);
    float direction = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(input3D, normal).normalized;
    direction *= input.magnitude; //preserve magnitude if the player wanted to do an in spot tech
    return techSpeed*direction;
}

Vector3 TechVelAdder2(Vector2 input, Vector3 normal, Quaternion rotation) //this will make the player tech in the input direction relative to what they perceive as forward
{
    float techSpeed = 10f;
    float input3D = new Vector3(input.x,0f, input.y);
    float direction = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(rotation*input3D, normal).normalized;
    direction *= input.magnitude;
    return techSpeed*direction;
}
```

If the `rotation*input3D` part confuses you, that's fine, it just means that the input3D vector should be relative to the player's rotation. What does that mean? If the player is facing right and they want to go forwards, go right instead.

Good luck, and hopefully this helped.